# InfoPath 2010 - Can I change what a showing default value on a dropdown based on a previous selection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a form where a dropdown has a value selected.
Is it possible to refresh the page somehow or another to change the value showing of another dropdown below?

For example:

If dropdown selection is "healthy groceries.
Then the dropdown below would default it's value to "fruits".
is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using rules, either on the first dropdown itself, or the form when it's loaded.

To set the second dropdown list's value once the form is loaded, you can navigate to the form load rules by selecting the "Data" tab and then clicking "Form Load":

[image]

You can also do this when you "change" the value of the dropdown, by adding a rule on the dropdown itself. Select the dropdown after that select "Manage Rules" from the ribbon:

[image]

This way you can set the value of the other dropdown list once the value of the current dropdown is changed.

Comment: Hello and thank you. Prior to asking I had used rules but maybe I am not using it correctly. I used it as such that if dropdown A is equal to "apple" then make dropdown B equal to "fruits". But I do not see Dropdown B change to fruits dynamically. Can I make it dynamically change? Dropdown A is just a several fields above Dropdown B and when it Dropdown A is changed, B remains unchanged.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the rules you're having? Where are you doing the rules? How are you setting the conditions?